# Email multiple attachments AND prefill email

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

I do following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { receiver });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris); // uris is a array list!
```

Then I tried adding following:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
```

this adds a log line complaining about that text is not an array list. Works though, but the email has no body

And alternatively i tried following:

```
ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < uris.size(); i++)
    texts.add("Test");
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, texts);
```

This removes the log warning, but the email still has no body.

**Question**

How can append multiple files to the mail AND prefill the body with some text?

Answer (score 1):

> How can append multiple files to the mail AND prefill the body with some text?

Generally speaking, you don't.

Quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE):

> get*ArrayListExtra can have **either** a EXTRA_TEXT **or** EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent

(emphasis added)

You are attempting to include both, which is outside the bounds of the `Intent` specification.

There are many apps that the user might choose from for your `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` `Intent`. What each of those apps does with your `Intent` is up to the developers of those apps. Likely candidates are:

- Ignore `EXTRA_TEXT`, as you are seeing
- Ignore `EXTRA_STREAM`
- Honor both
- Crash horribly

The same holds true with `ACTION_SEND` (you can have either `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM`, not both).

Comment: Seems like you're right, it's not supported... Still, this does not mean it does never work as you said. I would be happy with a solution that works with gmail/inbox at least... Although my attempt above seems to work for others, it's not working for me with inbox...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code, i used to attach multiple images to email.

`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
i.setType("image/png");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EMAIL SUBJECT");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email Body content....");`

Here i'm hard coding 2 images to arraylist which i need to send email intent chooser:

`Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slide_1);
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), largeIcon, "title", null);
Bitmap largeIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slide_2);
String path1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), largeIcon1, "title", null);
ArrayList<Uri> screenshotUri = new ArrayList<>();
screenshotUri.add(Uri.parse(path));
screenshotUri.add(Uri.parse(path1));`

Now `ArrayList<Uri>` added into intent method.

`i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail"));`

Hope this will help you...

Comment: I'm adding multiple text files and am doing the exact same thing as far as I see it. Adding `Uri`s as `ArrayList` and setting the text. Instead of putting my files in the media store, I have my own `ContentProvider` and share files from my apps cache directory... Sadly, this approach is not working with my inbox app... Whcih email app did you try that with?